# Custom post by Shortcode How to Show Wordpress Pagination (index.php)

Tags: php, wordpress

I replaced my blog post with my custom post by using shortcode in index.php but the pagination doesnt show.

here is my code

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>
  <div id="content-box" class="row">
   <main id="content" class="col-sm-9">
 
<?php echo do_shortcode('[ktzagcplugin_image source="yahoo" number="20" related="true" keyword="my blog keywords"]');?>

   </main>
   <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
            <?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>
  </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

it means there are 20 custom posts in my homepage, i wanna separate them by pagination. but it doesnt show.

Answer (score 0):

You need to review a code of [the_posts_pagination](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_posts_pagination/) function. This function is point to [get_the_posts_pagination](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_posts_pagination/). The last function getting global $`wp_query` variable and using it for create the pagination block.

I think you shortcode not initialize global variable $`wp_query` and `get_the_posts_pagination` hasn't data for create a pagination block.

You must to implement the pagination in plugin where your shortcode is implemented